# Some youtube videos will play in my app while others won't, why is that?

Tags: android

I made an Android App that plays some youtube videos that I uploaded and when I try to play some of them I get the error on my phone "There was an error while playing". Below is some code and two different videos, one will play while the other won't in the app.

```
public static final String VIDEO_ID = "xkeb0252FPc"; //this video will play

public static final String VIDEO_ID = "4W9yk15XkAU"; //this video won't play
```

Comment: Are you able to play the video with Youtube app on your mobile?

Comment: Yes, it plays with the Youtube App, but it won't play with my app.

Answer (score 0):

It's not you.  It's YouTube.

We ran into the exact same thing today.  Some videos we uploaded would play fine in both a web browser and the Android YouTube app, but failed using the YouTube Player API on Android with a visible "There was an error while playing" message in the UI and a YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason of INTERNAL_ERROR in our YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener.

This appears to be a transient problem with uploads to the YouTube server.  Uploading the exact same file to a different YouTube account would play fine under the  YouTube Player API, so it wasn't anything related to the video itself.  Deleting and re-uploading to the same account seemed to fix the problem sporadically.  Uploading to a new account seemed more reliable.